# How to deploy an existing VHD without any third party tool?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, vhd

I have created some VMs using Microsoft Hypervisor. I have the vhdx files for those VMs. now i want to use these same vhdx files to deploy new VMs on let's say other machines,or on the same machine with different names. IS it possible? If it is, Is it possible to deploy VHDs via a script?

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally tried but through Windows PowerShell you can do it. Refer following links for more details:

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/automate-the-hyper-v-virtual-machine-deployment-with-powershell

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj933287.aspx

https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-attach-existing-virtual-disk/